# Table spacing in html

Tags: html, css

For what ever reason, I get a small gap in between the two TD cells (Lines dont touch).
There is no padding or margin on that side... I did this collapsing idea.

Why is it there? http://jsfiddle.net/CKy6U/

My html:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            TEST CELL 1
        </td>
         <td>
             TEST CELL 2
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

my CSS:

```
table
{
    width: 100%;
}
tr
{
    border-bottom: 1px solid Black;
}

td
{
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 0px;
    border-left: 1px solid Black;
    border-bottom: 1px solid Black;
    padding: 3px;
    width: 50%;
}
```

My Result:
[image]

Comment: use  `border-collapse:collapse;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add Border Collapse for table.

```
table
{
width: 100%;
border-collapse:collapse;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/sureshponnukalai/CKy6U/3/)

Comment: Thanks. yes, i added it to the wrong group. Never thought to apply it to the whole thing. Thanks! Marking this as answer when i can, as it was first. But all answers are correct.

Answer (score 2):

You have to add `border-collapse: collapse` in your `table` or `cellspacing="0"` in your html table.

**css**

```
table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CKy6U/)

html:

```
<table cellspacing="0">
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CKy6U/9/)

Both solutions should work. But use `border-colapse` cause as @Mooseman comment `cellspacing` is obsolete in html5.

Comment: `cellspacing` is obsolete in HTML5. http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/table.html#table-constraints

Comment: Yes i know that. Just suggest an alternative.

Answer (score 2):

Add `border-right: 0px;` to and remove `border-collapse: separate` from the `td`. Add `border-collapse: collapse` to the `table`.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CKy6U/7/

Answer (score 2):

Try like this: [**LINK**](http://jsfiddle.net/CKy6U/2/)

**CSS:**

```
 table {
        width: 100%;
        border-collapse:collapse;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

use [normalize.css](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) or an [css reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)
Also I would add

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"> ... </table>
```

Comment: `cellspacing` and `cellpadding` are obsolete in HTML5. http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/table.html#table-constraints

Comment: @Mooseman okay, thanks for your comment. I had an issue with IE9.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `border-collapse` on the `td` and add it to the `table`

```
table{
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

tr{
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

td{
    border-spacing: 0px;
    border-left: 1px solid black;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    padding: 3px;
    width: 50%;
}
```